# Internal inductance of the outer conductor of a coaxial cable

Tags: inductance

Suppose there is a coaxial cable with the inner conductor in $ r < a$, vacuum in $ a<r<b$, and the outer conductor in $b < r < c$, what is the internal inductance of the outer conductor? Is it simply 0 due to the symmetry of the cylindrical geometry?

**Edit:**
The internal inductance per unit length of the inner conductor is:
$$ L_{in1} = \frac{\mu}{8\pi} $$

The external inductance per unit length inside the cable is:
$$ L_{ext} = \frac{\mu}{2\pi} \ln{\frac{b}{a}} $$

I'd like to figure out the internal inductance per unit length of the outer conductor $ L_{in2} $
where:
$$L_{\text{total}} = L_{in1} + L_{ext} + L_{in2}$$

There's a discussion of this in [here](http://www.g3ynh.info/zdocs/refs/NBS/Rosa1908.pdf), but it is very ambiguous and laconic in its derivation.

Comment: A coaxial cable has four terminals, so strictly speaking you need a four-pole matrix to describe it properly as a lumped element. If you were to try to measure the inductance of either the inner or the outer conductor all by themselves, then you would find that it matters on how you coil it up. You have to get the two terminals that you use for the measurement very close together to get a physically meaningful result. That's not different from the inductance of a simple wire. This, by the way, spells trouble with improperly terminated cables which have currents flowing trough the shield.

Comment: @CuriousOne I don't think I completely understood your comment, and I'm looking for a closed-form solution. This is from an exercise problem, so there is no need to be 'physically meaningful'.

Comment: You basically find the same caveat I just gave you in the Rosa paper. Defining the inductance of an open circuit like a straight wire is a stretch of imagination, but if that's what you are expected to do.... Why do you think the Rosa paper to be sketchy? It's old school, but it seems to get the job done. Looking at the latter part of the paper he actually does a very good job to motivate why the technically incorrect procedure leads to a very reasonable approximation in reality, anyway (except for the case of twisted conductors, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The internal inductance per unit length of the outer conductor is given by
$$\frac\mu{2\pi(c^2-b^2)}\left[\frac{c^4}{c^2-b^2}\ln \left(\frac cb\right)- \frac{c^2}2\right]-\frac\mu{8\pi}$$

you can deduce that formula in the same manner of deriving the formula of the  internal inductance of the inner conductor. The procedure is mentioned in the book of *David Cheng*
s '*Field and Wave Electromagnetics*' in chapter 6 on the static magnetic field.

Another procedure is to use the magnetic energy to derive the internal inductance via the relation: 
$$L = \left(2/I^2\right)\cdot Wm,$$  where $Wm$ is the magnetic stored energy in the outer conductor.